# Why can't a friend function access the private variables of an inherited class?

Tags: c++, class, oop

Isn't the `friend` function supposed to access everything that is in `Base` class and `Derived` class? `class Derived: public Base` -> everything that is in `private` in `Base` is now `public` inside the class derived.

```
class Base
{
private:
    int x;
};

class Derived : public Base
{
    int y;
public:
    void SetY(int value);
    void friend SetX(Derived &d);
};

void SetX(Derived &d)
{
    d.x = 100; // Why is this a problem?
               // Isn't Base supposed to be public now that is inherited?
}

int main()
{
    Derived d;
    SetX(d);
}
```

Comment: *public Base -> everything that is in private in Base is now public inside the class derived.* That's not how it works.  I suggested rereading how inheritance works in a [good C++ book](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list)

Comment: Research what `protected` means.  That should fix some misunderstandings you have of what `private` means.

Comment: If you want to access that `x` from the `Base` move your `friend` declaration into the `Base` and don't forget to forward declare `Derived`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your friend function `void friend SetX(Derived &d);` of `Derived` class is a friend function of that class only and it can only access private members of `Derived` class only but not allowed to access any private or protected member of a Base class. Also even from a Derieve class you can not access private members of a Base class but can access only the public and protected members. To reach/access the private members of a Base class you have to use public member function of base class.

There are two types of inheritance in C++

```
class B{};
class D:public B{};
```

All I mentioned above is applicable in the above case. Even though you inharite base `B` class as public to a Derieve class `D` all the private members inharites to Derieve `D` as private, protected members as protected and public as public.

But if you inharite as private like below all the members of Base class would be now private to the Derieve class.

```
  class B{};
  class D:private B{};
```

In this case a friend function can not even access any member of Base class `B`.

Comment: There is a little bit more to it than that since not even derived can access Base's private members.

Comment: True I am adding it. Thanks :-)

Comment: Might be worth making clear that `... : public Base` doesn't actually make all of `Base`'s members `public`, which I think was where OP was confused.

Answer (score 1):

> Isn't the `friend` function supposed to access everything that is in `Base` class and `Derived` class?

No. It is a friend of `Derived`, so it is supposed to access everything that the `Derived` class can access.

> `class Derived: public Base` -> everything that is in `private` in `Base` is now `public` inside the class derived.

No. Everything that was `private` in `Base` before, is still `private`.

The use of `public`/`protected`/`private` for inheritance [means something different](https://stackoverflow.com/a/860353/560648) than it does for member access control.